# Store and read hash and array in files in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file, hash, save

I'm a noob.I need some basic knowledge about how data should be saved and read under perl. Say to save a hash and an array. What format (extension) of file should be used? txt? So far I can only save all the things as string`print FILE %hash` and read them back as string`print <FILE>`. What should I do if I need my function hash and array inputs from a file. How to put them back to hash and array?

Comment: You may check out such modules as [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) or [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper).

Comment: **Data::Dumper** should help you to store array/hashes as it is. You can re-use them via **require/eval**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for data **serialisation**. Popular choices that are robust are [Sereal](http://p3rl.org/Sereal), [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON)[::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS) and [YAML::XS](http://p3rl.org/YAML::XS). Lesser known formats are: [ASN.1](http://enwp.org/ASN.1), [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/), [BERT](http://bert-rpc.org/), [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), [CBOR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7049), [JSYNC](http://jsync.org/), [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/), [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).

Other often mentioned choices are [Storable](http://p3rl.org/Storable) and [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) (or similar)/`eval`, but I cannot recommend them because Storable's format is Perl version dependent, and `eval` is unsafe because it executes arbitrary code. As of 2012, the parsing counter-part [Data::Undump](http://p3rl.org/Data::Undump) has not progressed very far yet. I also cannot recommend using XML because it does not map Perl data types well, and there exists multiple competing/incompatible schemas how to translate between XML and data.

---

Code examples (tested):

```
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json decode_json);
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
my %hash;
{
    my $json = encode_json \%hash;
    write_file('dump.json', { binmode => ':raw' }, $json);
}
{
    my $json = read_file('dump.json', { binmode => ':raw' });
    %hash = %{ decode_json $json };
}
```

---

```
use YAML::XS qw(Load Dump);
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
my %hash;
{
    my $yaml = Dump \%hash;
    write_file('dump.yml', { binmode => ':raw' }, $yaml);
}
{
    my $yaml = read_file('dump.yml', { binmode => ':raw' });
    %hash = %{ Load $yaml };
}
```

---

The next step up from here is [**object persistence**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281803/is-there-an-object-centric-perl-orm).

---

Also read: [Serializers for Perl: when to use what](http://blogs.perl.org/users/aristotle/2015/01/perl-serializers.html)

Answer (score 3):

Perlmonks has two good discussions on serialization.

- [How to save and reload my hash](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=510202)
- [How can I visualize my complex data structure?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=481746)

Answer (score 1):

This really depends upon how you'd like store your data in your file. I will try writing some basic perl code to enable you to read a file into an array and or write back a hash into a file.

```
#Load a file into a hash.
#My Text file has the following format.
#field1=value1
#field2=value2  
#<FILE1> is an opens a sample txt file in read-only mode.
my %hash;
while (<FILE1>)
{
  chomp;
  my ($key, $val) = split /=/;
  $hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? ",$val" : $val;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. using an existing CPAN module would be more appropriate rather than raw code.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to post it as a comment there.

Comment: Interesting and useful. This approach has value in some environments where modules aren't easy to install. I agree a preferred approach would be using Data::Dumper (which has come a long way in recent years) or another module.

Answer (score -1):

If you new I just suggest make to string from array/hash with join() and they write it with "print" and then read and use split() to make array/hash again. That would be more simple way like Perl teaching text book example.

Comment: and what would the disadvantages be?

Comment: It may be hard to deal with something even more complicated than  arrays or hashes (ex. multidimensional arrays).

Comment: And the real problems begin when the data can be any string, including containing the separator symbol.