# How to parse a text file having data in particular format and store it in hash using perl

Tags: perl, hash, text-parsing

I have a text file having some data in following format

```
%app_lookup_strings = (
                      common => {
                                  password => "password: ",
                                  select_action => "Select action => ",
                                  mgt_close => "BSA_MgtClose",
                                },
```

I have to read this data from text file and store it back in hash. I need to know how to parse a text file having such kind of data and store it in similar fashion of hash as shown above.

Comment: use `Storable` ;and to store `store \%app_lookup_strings, 'file.txt';` to get it back `my $ref = retrieve('file.txt');`

Comment: Related: [Store and read hash and array in files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684656/store-and-read-hash-and-array-in-files-in-perl), that question is more general than this one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text file just contains the one hash, the most straightforward solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = do 'text.file';

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'common' => {
                        'mgt_close' => 'BSA_MgtClose',
                        'password' => 'password: ',
                        'select_action' => 'Select action => '
                      }
        };
```