# A simple perl program to send data from different files

Tags: perl

I wrote a perl program which send the updated data from a file to remote server periodically. But now i want it to read it from differnt files and send the updated data such that the reciever should know how to seperate the data from the mixed data. Do i just need to put some kind of delimiter? Is there any standards already there for such things?

```
#############
#Change parameters
############
$PeerAddr='192.168.0.7';
$PeerPort='7070';
##############
# Import packages
##############
use Text::Diff;
use IO::Socket;
#############
# Define global variables
#############
$lineCount=0;
$loopCount=0;
our $stats2 = 0;
for($count = 0; $count <= 10000; $count++){
        my $data_dir="archive/otat/*dat";
        my $data_file= `ls -t $data_dir | head -1`;
        chomp($changed_data_file);
        print "old data_file is $changed_data_file \n";
        chomp($data_file);
        if($data_file ne $changed_data_file){
                $lineCount2=0;
                $changed_data_file=$data_file;
                print ("String:$data_file :$changed_data_file  are not equal\n");
                }
        while(defined($data_file)){
                print "$data_file \n";
                open (DAT,$data_file) || die("Could not open file! $!");
                @iofile = <DAT>;
                $lineCount = @iofile;
                splice(@diffLines);
                print "printing: $lineCount\n";
                print "printing 2: $lineCount2 \n";
                chomp $lineCount;
                chomp $lineCount2;
                if($lineCount != $lineCount2){
                        $j=0;
                        for($i=$lineCount2;$i <= $lineCount; $i++){
                        $diffLines[$j] = $iofile[$i];
                                $j++;
                }
                        $num=@diffLines;
                        print "count of diff lines:$num\n";
                        $lineCount2 = $lineCount;
                        $loopCount=0;
                }
                if($loopCount>2){
                        $loopCount=0;
                        print "Look for recent file \n";
                        last;
                }
                $loopCount++;
                sleep(5);
############################
                &socket_con(@diffLines);
        }

}
#### Methods/Functions
sub socket_con {
        if ($sock== 0){
                $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                                        PeerAddr => $PeerAddr,
                                                        PeerPort => $PeerPort,
                                                        Proto => 'tcp'
                                                        );
                die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;
        }
        print $sock @_;
#close($sock);
}
```

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Comment: Employ [serialisation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10684780).

Comment: @Quentin I cannot open the link which you commented.

Comment: Wouldn't either having the server accepting commands (like "PARSE TYPE1") or sending structured data, think YAML/JSON/XML, be a pretty good way to achieve what you're after?

Comment: @Jon which one is best YAML or JSON or XML?

Comment: @user1595858 Best for what?  YAML is extremely easy for humans to read and write.  JSON is a little harder to read and write (though not much so), but is arguably even easier to parse than YAML.  XML is more difficult to write, and more difficult to parse.  But provides mechanisms not available to YAML and JSON (which is why it was useful as a foundation for XHTML).  There are more differences: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats

Comment: [XML is badly suited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10684780), I don't recommend it

Comment: Short version - unless you run into some limitations that JSON can't handle but XML can (possible but unlikely), stick to JSON.

Comment: @DavidO I want to move the data over to remote server. So i am looking for something which will pack the data so that it will not consume huge bandwidth. Does it sounds good if i conver the data in jason format and then pack it?

Comment: @user1595858 If it's data that works with JSON go for JSON. gzipping (or some other preferred packing)  the data can make a lot of sense if you want to save bw, but don't forget to consider the time it may take to unpack, and the cpu/memory usage if it's a large chunk of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used JSON a lot with good results http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON   You can store your data in a hash, serialize it, send the text to the client and have it turn the string back into a Perl hash for easy use.  For example:

```
# on the server
use JSON;
...
# store changed lines in a hash
$diffLines->{$data_file}[$j]=$io_file[$i];
...
# Serialize the hash reference into a string which you then send to the client
$diffLinesSerialized = encode_json $diffLines;

# on the clinet
use JSON;
...
# convert received data from serialized string into hash
$diffLines = decode_json $diffLinesSerialized;
# $diffLines is now a has reference which can be accessed like normal
foreach my $data_file (keys %$diffLines) {
  foreach my $line (@{$diffLines->{$data_file}}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

All this being said, as much as I don't really like XML from a programming perspective, it is a prevalent standard for this kind of thing.  If this is just a specialized, internal tool that won't grow into something larger it probably doesn't matter, but if you think this could turn into a more general service, say for non-perl clients, it would be good to consider XML as an option.  Programming from a service-oriented perspective can make it easier to grow things down the road.

Comment: the only question i have is, i dont want to install json.pm in each client machine, can i have json.pm withing my code package?

Comment: To do this using core modules, you can serialize using `Data::Dumper` and `eval`, however, you probably should just do it right and use JSON.