# Read XML file into user Perl class using XML::Simple

Tags: perl, serialization, xml-simple

I have a Perl object containing one scalar and two arrays of hashes.

I am using [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple) to save an XML copy of this data structure, but when I try to read in the XML file using `XMLin` I am getting a different data structure.

Is there any way to specify the structure in `XMLin` to take the format of the object I used to create the original XML file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're creating XML just for the purposes of storing the data in your object?

If so you should look at something like [`FreezeThaw`](https://metacpan.org/module/FreezeThaw) or [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) instead, which is meant for this purpose and will recreate and bless the object properly.

Depending on the data, even [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) might help you, but `XML::Simple` isn't very good at doing what it's intended for never mind about serializing arbitrary data structures.

Comment: I am actually trying to accomplish a few things.  First I am trying to parse a text file into my data structure then output this data structure to xml format which I can do successfully. After that I am trying to read in the exact same xml file into my data structure so I can do more processing based on event driven feedback and output the new xml file with the additional tags that were originally blank filled in. I am then going to take this new xml file and apply an xslt script to it for further processing.

Comment: Then is the data structure open for change? I mean, would a proper DOM representation of the XML be acceptable? That is the only way you are going to get reproducible XML.

Comment: [Avoid Storable.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684656/store-and-read-hash-and-array-in-files-in-perl)

Comment: The xml should be in proper DOM representation.

Comment: @user2479059: I mean the *internal* representation. Can the form of the object be changed?