# Perl--Can I save variables in workspace?

Tags: perl, workspace

Is it possible to save the variables or just a hash in perl workspace? For example, this can be done in Matlab with 'save' function.

edit: I am reading several text files and generating a hash out of them. When a new text file comes, I want to update this hash w/o re-doing everything from the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: Perl doesn't have a persistent "workspace".  I'm not sure what you're referring to.  Are you working in some sort of IDE?

Comment: No. I am reading several text files and generating a hash out of them. When a new text file comes, I want to update this hash w/o re-doing everything from the beginning. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eg. the [Storeble](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.39/Storable.pm) module or [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML) or [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) to save the hash between sessions.

Comment: [Avoid Storable.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684656/store-and-read-hash-and-array-in-files-in-perl)