# Storable binary image v60.156 more recent than I am (v2.10) at

Tags: perl

I am using perl 5.20.3 and using Storable.pm to freeze and thaw blob data.

I am getting error while thaw:

```
Storable binary image v60.156 more recent than I am (v2.10) at /opt/app/brix/perl/lib/5.20.3/i686-linux-thread-multi/Storable.pm line 418
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
my $thawed = thaw($agg_blob);
```

Comment: How do you `freeze` your data and where do you store it? You might need to update `Storable` and/or use some encoding-decoding.

Comment: It could be that the `$agg_blob` was stored with a different `perl` / `Storable.pm` that was more recent than the one you are trying to read it with. Then you might have to restore it with the newer version, or if that is not possible: try to downgrade the current version to the older version

Comment: I tried using decode and encode but still same error.

Comment: I am using same module to freeze and thaw.

Comment: In order to side-step the problem, [use a different serialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684780/46395).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case data is already stored in DB and now i cant change data store logic. Please guide me if there is a way to read blob data from DB without using thaw, though data is already stored using storable freez.

Comment: v60.156 isn't anywhere close to being a valid Storable version. Either the file wasn't created by Storable, or it has gotten messed up by encoding issues when being written or read, or when copied around between systems.

Comment: DB usually has a storage encoding and connection encoding. It might change your data. Check that you get the same binary data from your DB.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I resolved this issue, and actual issue was with the data. BLOB data was getting truncated some how hence it was giving issue in thaw function. Error massage is totally wrong and very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help. Issue is resolved now. Actual issue was with the data. BLOB data was getting truncated some how hence it was giving issue in thaw function. Error massage (Storable binary image v60.156 more recent than I am (v2.10) ....) is totally wrong and very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

you are most probably serializing something, which you think you are de-serializing, which is not the case ...

```
sub setData {
   my $self       = shift ;
   my $config = ${ shift @_ } || croak 'no config provided !!!' ;
   my $key        = shift ;
   my $data       = shift ;
   my $server  = $config->{'env'}->{'redis'}->{'server'};
   my $port    = $config->{'env'}->{'redis'}->{'port'};
   my $serialized = freeze ($data);
   my $redis = Redis->new('server' => "$server:$port");
   $redis->set($key => $serialized);
}

sub getData {
       my $self       = shift ;
       my $config = ${ shift @_ } || croak 'no config provided !!!' ;
       my $key        = shift ;
       my $server  = $config->{'env'}->{'redis'}->{'server'};
       my $port    = $config->{'env'}->{'redis'}->{'port'};
       my $redis = Redis->new('server' => "$server:$port");
       my $serialized = $redis->get($key);
       my $data = thaw($serialized);
       return $data ;
}
```